# Error: Unknown public property "name" of element <LIGHTNING-INPUT-FIELD>. This is likely a typo on the corresponding attribute "name"

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

I am getting this issue in the console:
Error: Unknown public property "name" of element . This is likely a typo on the corresponding attribute "name".

However, this component was working properly before and this issue doesn't show up when I login with another user.

Both the user have the same user profile.
I also checked the API version of lwc - it is breaking 50.0 and 51.0 both

Can anyone please help with why this issue happens? as I am not able to find any possible reasoning for this.

Here is the code sample:

```
<lightning-input-field name="Address" field-name={memberPermanentStreetapi} 
    value={memberPermanentStreet} onchange={handleDemoChange}>
</lightning-input-field>
```

Comment: This still throws an error inside of the console for me, which is very strange considering that [Salesforce's own documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) uses the 'name' attribute in an example under **Resetting Individual Fields**. Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and identified the reason to be 'Debug Mode' enabled for the user. Once I disabled the Debug mode, the issue was resolved. It doesn't make much sense and looks like a Salesforce bug, but that's the resolution I had done.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to the fact that you are trying to pass a value to a parameter that does not exist. lightning-input-field component doesn't have the 'name' parameter
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification